# how to use horizontalscroll view component?

Tags: android

i want to create a horizontal scroll view just like the one shown in image[image: horizontal scroll view]

In android widgets i found Horizontal Scroll View widget in composite section but dont know how to use it.Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `xml file` and add `HorizontalScrollView` first then add one layout to this as child. Then you can add any no. of views to the newly added child, that makes entire things `scroll`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <!--  child views here -->
        </RelativeLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what should i put inside relative layout a list view or what to display English,french & all that just like shown in image ? thanks for reply

Comment: @vaibvorld you are not supposed to use listview and scrollview together. It gives uncertain results. Rather to your requirement, add textviews or buttons that display the things in a linearlayout with horizontal orientation or relative layout as said above.